# Delphi 10 aes 128 ecb calculator error

Tags: delphi, encryption, aes, calculator, turbopower

I am using TurboPower Lockbox 3. It does not give the right result, where do I make mistakes ?

I am doing the right calculation on this site.

[Aes calculator](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc/index?key=783490FD6A6C90F07236A8ED402794F8732C96FB711FA0F46C349AC4792493E8&iv=00000000000000000000000000000000&input=000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F&mode=ecb&action=Encrypt&output=E6861877DB7B021E8B755F927243ED7B)

I am calculating the python and I get correct result.

correct result.

'E6861877DB7B021E8B755F927243ED7B'

There are different results when I calculate it as delphi.

```
function EncryptText_AES_128(input: string; password: string): ansistring;
var
  Codec: TCodec;
  CipherText: String;
begin
  Codec := TCodec.Create(nil);
  try
    Codec.CryptoLibrary := TCryptographicLibrary.Create(Codec);
    //
    Codec.StreamCipherId := BlockCipher_ProgID;
    Codec.BlockCipherId := Format(AES_ProgId, [128]);
    Codec.ChainModeId := ecb_ProgId;
    //
    Codec.Password := Password;
    Codec.EncryptString(input, CipherText,tencoding.UTF8);
    //
    Result := (CipherText);
  finally
    Codec.Free;
  end;
end;
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
memo1.Lines.Add( EncryptText_AES_128(#$00#$01#$02#$03#$04#$05#$06#$07#$08#$09#$0a#$0b#$0c#$0d#$0e#$0f,#$78#$34#$90#$fd#$6a#$6c#$90#$f0#$72#$36#$a8#$ed#$40#$27#$94#$f8#$73#$2c#$96#$fb#$71#$1f#$a0#$f4#$6c#$34#$9a#$c4#$79#$24#$93#$e8));
end;
```

where am I making mistakes ?

Comment: How is the string encoded?

Comment: string not exist as chr.

Comment: python code. plaintext = b''
    for k in range(0, 16):
        # Assemble 0x00 0x01 0x02 ... 0x1F byte-array
        print(int_as_byte(k))
        plaintext += int_as_byte(k)

Comment: Please don't ask in comments

Comment: What on earth do you mean with "Delphi XE10"? There is no Delphi XE10. The highest XE version is XE8. After that, I only know Delphi 10 Seattle, Delphi 10.1 Berlin and Delphi 10.2 Tokyo. Which one is it?

Comment: FWIW, it is not necessary to get a new account each time you want to ask a question. I see you have two very similar accounts. Why?

Comment: I did not kill the man, please be calm... I'm a novice, please tell me my mistakes and let me fix it -_-

Comment: Everyone is calm. But even novices can be expected to read the guidelines and to watch how others behave.

Answer (score 2):

I already told you in your old question [Aes 128 ecb delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50893964/aes-128-ecb-delphi) that `#$78#$34#$90#$fd#$6a#$6c#$90#$f0#$72#$36#$a8#$ed#$40#$27#$94#$f8#$73#$2c#$96#$fb#$71#$1f#$a0#$f4#$6c#$34#$9a#$c4#$79#$24#$93#$e8` is no 128 bit key.

I can reproduce the output of
your online-calculator with my own routine if I use **AES-256-ECB**. Here the complete program and output

```
uses
  aes_type, aes_ECB, mem_util;
var
  Context: TAESContext;
  ct: array[0..50] of byte;
const
  pt: array[0..15] of byte = ($00,$01,$02,$03,$04,$05,$06,$07,
                              $08, $09,$0a,$0b,$0c,$0d,$0e,$0f);
const
  key256 : array[0..31] of byte = ($78,$34,$90,$fd,$6a,$6c,$90,$f0,
                                   $72,$36,$a8,$ed,$40,$27,$94,$f8,
                                   $73,$2c,$96,$fb,$71,$1f,$a0,$f4,
                                   $6c,$34,$9a,$c4,$79,$24,$93,$e8);
begin
  AES_ECB_Init_Encr(key256, 256, context);
  AES_ECB_Encrypt(@pt, @ct, sizeof(pt), context);
  writeln(hexstr(@ct, sizeof(pt)));
end.

D:\BP_WE\WORK\AES\BASE>C:\Programme\BORLAND\DELPHI6\Bin\DCC32 -uC:\Programme\BOR
LAND\DELPHI6\LIB;. -b -q -cc t_ecb.pas
Borland Delphi Version 14.0
Copyright (c) 1983,2002 Borland Software Corporation
6290 lines, 0.11 seconds, 13144 bytes code, 6805 bytes data.

D:\BP_WE\WORK\AES\BASE>T_ECB.EXE
e6861877db7b021e8b755f927243ed7b
```

If I use AES-128 the result is `df6dfb1fca78323413c9ec48a3162b0a`. Therefore if you want to get the same output as your calculator use AES-256.